# Output items from XML feed when matching to category

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, categories

I've exported all product items from my shop as an XML-File and parsed these items with PHP in my single.php of my theme. The parse works fine so far.

Now i want to only display products which category name matches with the ones that have been set in the article editor of WP. This is my code:

```
<?php

    // Parse XML Feed
    $html = "";
    $url = "http://example.com/feed.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $item = $xml->channel->item;
    $categories = get_the_category();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($item); $i++){
        $title = $item[$i]->title;
        $link = $item[$i]->link;
        $category = $item[$i]->category;
        $img = $item[$i]->description->a->img["src"];

        // This approach breaks my site. A loop in another loop seems not to be that good
        // foreach ($categories as $i => $cat) {
        //   $catName = $cat->name;

        //   if (preg_match("/\b$catName\b/", $category)) {
        //     $html .= "
        //       <a href='$link'><h3>$title</h3>
        //       <img src='$img'>
        //       <p>$category</p></a>
        //       <hr>";
        //     }
        //   }

        if (preg_match("/\bCATEGORY_NAME\b/", $category)) {
          $html .= "
        <a href='$link'><h3>$title</h3>
        <img src='$img'>
        <p>$category</p></a>
        <hr>";
        }
    }

    echo $html;
  ?>
```

If i change `CATEGORY_NAME` to an category name which exits, then the output works like i want. The other approach with that loop breaks my site with an "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of *** bytes exhausted…".

Would love to hear some tips

EDIT: Here is some example code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <atom:link href="www.example.com/export.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <title>www.example.com</title>
        <description>desc</description>
        <link>www.example.com</link>
        <language>1-1</language>
        <image>
            <url>www.example.com/logo.gif</url>
            <title>test page</title>
            <link>http://example.com</link>
        </image>
        <item>
            <title>Example item</title>
            <guid>www.example.com/item</guid>
            <link>www.example.com/item</link>
            <description>
                <a href="www.example.com/item" style="border:0 none;">
                    <img src="www.example.com/image.png" align="right" style="padding: 0pt 0pt 12px 12px; float: right;" />
                </a>
            </description>
            <category>Categoryname</category>
            <pubDate>Thu, 24 Aug 2017 17:19:17 +0200</pubDate>rn</item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the data your trying to process?